# At which points is this complex function differentiable

Tags: derivatives

I'm making an exercise about the derivative. I needed to prove that $f(x)=|x|$ isn't differentiable at zero. Now I was wondering if we had a function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} :z \to |z|$ so a complex function, in which points is this $f$ differentiable.

If we say $z=a+bi$, for $a=b=0$ it's not differentiable and for $a$ not equal to zero and $b=0$ it's differentiable (I think) but are there other problematic points for this function?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $g(z)=f^2(z)=f^2(x+yi)=x^2+y^2\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $g$ is differentiable $\iff$ $f$ is constant by Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: what do you mean by: f is constant by cauchy riemann equations?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html

Comment: isn't it $f^{2}(z)$=$|x^{2}-y^{2}+2xyi|$ EDIT: i'm sorry i confussed it with absolut value

Comment: if $f(z)=f(x+yi)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then $f^2(x+yi)=(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2=x^2+y^2$. What you were doing is $f(z^2)$.

Comment: correct i'm sorry

Comment: but i'm not sure how i can prove in which points f is differentiable

Comment: but i'm not sure how i can prove in which points f is differentiable. Because it's not because g is differentiable in a point that f is differentiable in that point. The other implicitation is valid but not this one.

Comment: Mathmath, what you're missing here is the standard exercise that a *real-valued* complex-differentiable function must be constant. Write $g = u+iv$ and note that $v=0$, so $\partial u/\partial x = \partial u/\partial y = 0$.